# Mavenlink API with node

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am trying to connect to mavenlink using node, but i keep getting an oauth2 validation error. Every solution online pertains to token generation for many users, but i just need to manipulate the data for use in an internal app. Does anyone have an example of oauth2 authentication for one user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oauth2 authentication in this case is achieved with `"Authorization": "Bearer key".toString('base64')` inside of the headers option.

```
var https = require("https");

function printError (error) {
    console.error(error);
}

key = 'oauth2 token';
var options = {
  host: 'api.mavenlink.com',
  path: '/api/v1/workspaces.json',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer key".toString('base64')
      }
};

var body = "";

var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log('statusCode: ', res.statusCode);
  console.log('headers: ', res.headers);

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);

  });

  res.on('data', function (chunks){
    body += chunks;
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    if(res.statusCode == 200) {
      try
      {
        //parse data
        var massData = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(body);
      } catch(error) {
        //parse error
        printError(error);
      }
    }
  });
});
```